# Figure and table in one float

Tags: spacing, floats

I was trying to put a figure directly above a table in a TeX document, which I achieved by putting the command `\includegraphics` directly after `\begin{table}`. This, however, leaves no space between the figure and the table and even `\vspace` can't fix that.

Is there any other way to position a figure right above a table in the same float and still leaving some space between figure and table?

I won't need to reference the figure, so it doesn't need to have a caption or label, it only needs to be in the same float environment with the table. I tried putting everything in a `minipage` but I can only make it work with either two figures or two tables.

Comment: If you want captions for both, you can use `\captionof` for one of them. I believe there are other questions here that involve figures and tables in the same float as well.

Answer (score 6):

`\vspace` and other vertical spacing commands can fix it. A blank line after the figure would cause a paragraph break, which is recommendable there. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}  
\begin{table}[ht]
\includegraphics{test}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Text
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow ok so I just missed the blank line! Thanks!